# current_page inability to identify the 'home' page route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am currently making an app having the following routes for my application.

```
refix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
        home GET    /home(.:format)              pages#home
    problems GET    /problems(.:format)          problems#index
             POST   /problems(.:format)          problems#create
 new_problem GET    /problems/new(.:format)      problems#new
edit_problem GET    /problems/:id/edit(.:format) problems#edit
     problem GET    /problems/:id(.:format)      problems#show
             PATCH  /problems/:id(.:format)      problems#update
             PUT    /problems/:id(.:format)      problems#update
             DELETE /problems/:id(.:format)      problems#destroy
```

The `_navigation` partial file as per follow

```
      <% if !current_page?(home_path) and   !current_page?(root_path) %>
        <bold>Home</bold>  | &nbsp;
      <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Home", home_path %> | &nbsp;
      <% end %>

      <% if !current_page?(problems_path) %>
        <%= link_to "Problem list", problems_path %> | &nbsp;
      <% else %>
        <bold>Problem list</bold>  | &nbsp;
      <% end %>

      <% if !current_page?(new_problem_path) %> 
        <%= link_to "Add new problem", new_problem_path %> | &nbsp;
      .......
```

Now when I navigate to "problem, add new problem" I do not get the "home" with the link.

any advices to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try it like :

```
<% if controller_name == "pages" %>
        <bold>Home</bold>  | &nbsp;
      <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Home", home_path %> | &nbsp;
      <% end %>
```